# How to force a browser to request an image from another site using https?

Tags: http, iis, ssl, https

I have a site, say `mysite.com` and it displays some images from another site, say `anothersite.com`. Both these sites have valid certificates and https works for both of them. My question is how to make browser requests images from `anothersite.com` using http if client browse `http://mysite.com` and use https when they browse `https://mysite.com`?

I'm trying omitting protocol in my image element `<img src="//anothersite.com/image.jpg" />` but it doesn't work, browser doesn't display secure connection (lock with yellow triangle in Chrome). If I specify `<img src="https://anothersite.com/image.jpg" />` Chrome displays green lock, but I don't want to request images using https when user browses `mysite.com` using http.

Both sites are run on IIS if that's important.

Thank you.

Comment: The relative src link with `//` in the beginning should work. Are you sure thats what chrome is angry about?

Comment: Sorry guys, feeling awkward, it does work now but didn't work when I tried before asking the question, apparently caching issue. The answer is in the question, what does SO do with the questions like this?